# How can i do input validations when user inputs values directly into objects?-JAVA

Tags: java, oop

Is this possible to achieve or have i wrongly understood this question?
This is the question:

Implement a class MyDate that has integer data members to store month, day,
and year. The class should have a three-parameter constructor that allows the
date to be set at the time a new MyDate object is created. If the user creates a
MyDate object without passing any arguments, or if any of the values passed
are invalid, the default values of 1, 1, 2001 (i.e., January 1, 2001) should be
used. The class should have member functions to print the date in the following
formats: 

 3/15/10

 March 15, 2010

 15 March 2010

Demonstrate the usage of class MyDate by writing a class TestMyDate with a
main method that declares an object of type MyDate and displays it using all
the 3 formats.
Input Validation: Only accept values between 1 and 12 for the month, between
1 and 31 for the day, and between 1950 and 2020 for the year.

I've implemented this question but i can't seem to validate user input when the value is inserted at the time a new object is created. How can i do this? Please don't tell me to do research because i have done it. If Google could provide me with the answer i wouldn't have come here. Please help me.

Here's my codes:

The MyDate class:

```
package Number1;

public class MyDate {

private int month;
private int day;
private int year;

public MyDate()
{
    month = 1;
    day = 1;
    year = 2001;
}

public MyDate(int m,int d,int y)
{
    this.month = m;
    this.day = d;
    this.year = y;
}

public int getMonth()
{
    return month;
}

public int getDay()
{
    return day;
}

public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}

public void Format1()
{
    int m,d,y,afterM;
    m = getMonth();
    d = getDay();
    y = getYear();

    afterM = y % 100;

    System.out.println(""+m+"/"+d+"/"+afterM);
}

public void Format2()
{
    int m,d,y;
    String word = null;
    m = getMonth();
    d = getDay();
    y = getYear();

    switch(m)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        word = "January";
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        word = "February";
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        word = "March";
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        word = "April";
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        word = "May";
        break;
    }
    case 6:
    {
        word = "June";
        break;
    }
    case 7:
    {
        word = "July";
        break;
    }
    case 8:
    {
        word = "August";
        break;
    }
    case 9:
    {
        word = "September";
        break;
    }
    case 10:
    {
        word = "October";
        break;
    }
    case 11:
    {
        word = "November";
        break;
    }
    case 12:
    {
        word = "December";
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1-12");
        break;
    }
    }

    System.out.println(""+word+" "+d+","+y);
}

public void Format3()
{
    int m,d,y;
    String word = null;
    m = getMonth();
    d = getDay();
    y = getYear();

    switch(m)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        word = "January";
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        word = "February";
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        word = "March";
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        word = "April";
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        word = "May";
        break;
    }
    case 6:
    {
        word = "June";
        break;
    }
    case 7:
    {
        word = "July";
        break;
    }
    case 8:
    {
        word = "August";
        break;
    }
    case 9:
    {
        word = "September";
        break;
    }
    case 10:
    {
        word = "October";
        break;
    }
    case 11:
    {
        word = "November";
        break;
    }
    case 12:
    {
        word = "December";
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1-12");
        break;
    }
    }

    System.out.println(""+d+" "+word+" "+y);

}
}
```

The main TestMyDate:

```
package Number1;

public class TestMyDate {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyDate D = new MyDate(7,23,2013);

    D.Format1();
    System.out.println();
    D.Format2();
    System.out.println();
    D.Format3();

}

}
```

These codes only returns the dates in these different formats. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I fail to see where the disconnect is. In the constructor, put some if-statements checking to make sure the arguments are valid. What exactly are you not understanding?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do the validation and `throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal date")` in `MyDate()` to make all the client code strictly conform the rule:

```
public MyDate(int m,int d,int y)
{
    // do some validate here
    if (!validate(m, d, y))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal date")
    this.month = m;
    this.day = d;
    this.year = y;
}

private boolean validate(int m, int d, int y){
    // use here as the central place of your validation (Format1(), Format2(), Format3(), ...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you

- input the values you need to read
- validate the inputs are you go.
- *only once* you have valid data create the object.

I suggest you don't use a class to input it's own values.  This is making the class overly complicated.

I also suggest you use arrays instead of long switch statements.  You can replace your switch statements with two lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your validation in the constructor before assigning them to the member variables. Your best bet would be to create private methods that return a bool so you can reuse the logic in the event that you add setters to those properties.

```
public MyDate(int m, int d, int y)
{
    if (monthIsValid(m)) {
        this.month = m;
    }
    if (dayIsValid(d)) {
        this.day = d;
    }
    if (yearIsValid(y)) {
        this.year = y;
    }
}
```

Having the switch statement is fine, though I'd only have it in a single place, and call it from both `Format` methods.

Comment: There's a lot more you can (and probably should do), like checking to see if any of the properties failed at the end of the constructor, but as this is an assignment, you should be fine not worrying about it.

Comment: You should always go for extrapolating that kind of logic that can (or will) be reused. If I was a professor, I'd teach that by expanding a class like this in the next assignment as well to get people out of the habit of doing "throwaway" code like many students do (as it's all they know).

Comment: You probably should become a professor. :) I haven't been taught that in class but i'll follow your advice.

Comment: @krillgar the switch will work but it is an gross amount of code to do a simple task. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey True, but other uses of switch statements are a little harder to come by in school settings. Arrays and Dictionaries are easier to demonstrate.